# Firebase DataSnapshot.forEach doesn't break after returning true

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

the documentation of the DataSnapshot states that to exit a forEach loop you should use `return true;`

Now I have this piece of code in a Firebase Cloud Function

```
    db.collection("waiting_users").orderBy("start_time", "desc").get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                if (_checkIntersection(doc.data().languages, newValue.languages)) {
                    console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data().start_time);
                    db.collection("chats").doc().set({participants: [snap.id, doc.id]});
                    return true;
                }
            });
            return true;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error getting documents", err);
        });
```

Inside the if-statement I'm returning true so I would expect the loop to stop after it found an intersection but it doesn't.
Returning true only seems to actually stop the loop if it is in front of the if-statement, if I'm returning true after the if-statement it also won't work.

Comment: That's because you're returning inside the callback.

Comment: Where is the documentation that suggests you can return true to break the loop?  I think you might be referring to Realtime Database docs instead of Firestore.  Firestore forEach isn't documented to have this behavior.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#forEach

Comment: @DougStevenson You're referring to the Client SDK while I'm using the Admin SDK because I'm using Cloud Functions. As DataSnapshot isn't even documented  in the Admin SDK I assumed it's identical to admin.database.DataSnapshot and therefore would have the same forEach behaviour.

Comment: @Li357 could you please explain this further, as I don't have that much experience with JavaScript? As far as I can tell the return relevant to the callback happens at a later stage, so the other return should work as expected and end the loop

Comment: Firestore doesn't have a DataSnapshot.  It has a DocumentSnapshot.  They're very different.  The Firestore API docs can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/

Comment: @DougStevenson will that feature be added to the Firestore SDK and do you have any suggestions for a workaround?

Answer (score -3):

To break a loop in javascript, you need to use the reserved key `break`. `return` is used to break a function execution.

Comment: This is not a JavaScript loop.  It's a special forEach provided by the Firebase SDK, and it has special semantics.